# Trying to format returned _set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to populate my form with a list of plans.

Here is my unicode for the Plans model

```
def __unicode__(self):
    label = "ID: %s, Member(s): %s, Plan Type: %s" % (self.id, self.get_owners(), self.plan_type)
    return unicode(label)
```

Now I call get_owners which is shown below:

```
def get_owners(self):
    owners = self.planmember_set.filter(ownership_type__code__in=["primary","joint"])
    return owners
```

But my output shows:

```
[<PlanMember: Name, [membership_type]><PlanMember: Name, etc etc>]
```

How do I go about displaying the output without the brackets, and more along the lines of:

```
Name [membership_type], Name [membership_type], etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just returning the raw queryset from `get_owners`, and Python is calling `repr()` on that to insert it into the string.

The best bet is to do the formatting within `get_owners`:

```
def get_owners(self):
    owners = ...
    return u", ".join(unicode(o) for o in owners)
```

Comment: Im shown this error when I try that:

`Caught TypeError while rendering: sequence item 0: expected string, PlanMember found`

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_owners` method is doing exactly what it should do: return a set of owners. In your template you can then loop over these owners and display them however you like:

```
{% for owner in plan.get_owners %}
    {{ owner }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, inside other python code, you can compose it into a string as you like:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    owners = u', '.join(self.get_owners())
    label = "ID: %s, Member(s): %s, Plan Type: %s" % (self.id, owners, self.plan_type)
    return unicode(label)
```

Model methods shouldn't enforce display; they should only return data. (Except for obvious exceptions like `__unicode__` which is specifically about how to display the model as unicode text.)

Comment: I get the same error as I got with Daniels response.  I get that you can loop through on the template but what if its a form field you are trying to populate and not just displaying info on the template?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a `__unicode__` method to `PlanMember` as you did for `Plan`.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    label = "Name: %s, [%s]" % (self.name, self.membership_type)
    return unicode(label)
```

Comment: A `__repr__` method might be what you're looking for instead.